# How to create PL/SQL function in package

Tags: oracle, plsql

How to create `PL/SQL` **function** `get_amount` which returns `acc_amount` for `acc_id`,
and **function** `get_date` which returns `acc_date` for `acc_id`.

Here you have package and package body, how I make last two functions.

This I work like exercise.

I think my other code is fine.

I'm beginner in Oracle and pl/sql, maybe my question is stupid

I am sorry if i did not explain well, My english is not very good.

Thank you all for the answer!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE account_api AS

PROCEDURE add_new_account
    (
      p_acc_id     accounts.acc_id%type
    , p_acc_name   accounts.acc_name%type
    , p_acc_amount accounts.acc_amount%type
    , p_acc_date   accounts.acc_date%type
);

PROCEDURE upd_account   
    (
      p_acc_name   accounts.acc_name%type
    , p_acc_amount accounts.acc_amount%type
    , p_acc_date   accounts.acc_date%type
);

PROCEDURE del_accounts
    (
      p_acc_id     accounts.acc_id%type
);

FUNCTION get_amount 
    (p_acc_id      accounts.acc_id%type)
    RETURN number;

FUNCTION get_date 
    (p_acc_date    accounts.acc_date%type)
    RETURN date;  

end account_api;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY account_api AS

PROCEDURE add_new_account
    (
      p_acc_id     accounts.acc_id%type
    , p_acc_name   accounts.acc_name%type
    , p_acc_amount accounts.acc_amount%type
    , p_acc_date   accounts.acc_date%type
)
IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO account (acc_id, acc_name, acc_amount, acc_date)
    VALUES (acc_seq.nextval, p_acc_id, p_acc_name, p_acc_amount, p_acc_date)
END;

PROCEDURE upd_account
    (
      p_acc_name   accounts.acc_name%type
    , p_acc_amount accounts.acc_name%type
    , p_acc_date   accounts.acc_name%type
)
IS
BEGIN
    UPDATE accounts
        SET acc_naziv  = p_acc_naziv
          , acc_amount = p_acc_amount
          , acc_date   = p_acc_date
    WHERE ---------------------------------
COMMIT;
END;

PROCEDURE del_accounts
    (
      p_acc_id     accounts.acc_id%type
)

DELETE FROM accounts WHERE acc_id = p_acc_id;
COMMIT;


FUNCTION get_amount
    (
      p_acc_id    accounts.acc_id%type
)



FUNCTION get_date
    (
       p_acc_id    accounts.acc_id%type
)
```

Comment: In order to make your code better readable, I suggest `PROCEDURE upd_account ... END upd_account;` instead of just `END;`

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
FUNCTION get_amount(p_acc_id accounts.acc_id%type) return Number is
 res number;
begin 
 select acc_amount into res 
 from  account where acc_id =p_acc_id; 
 return res;
end;
```

You select the value into a variable and then return that variable.

Also, have in mind that the above code could cause an exception if no data is found 
(wrong `p_acc_id` is given)

I leave the second implementation to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a `cursor` try this one.

```
function get_amount(p_acc_id in number) return t_cursor is
    v_cursor t_cursor
Begin
open v_cursor for 
    select * from  account 
    where acc_id =p_acc_id; 
    return v_cursor;
End get_amount;
```

But you should define `type t_cursor IS REF Cursor;` in your package header.